# Adding metadata on images gives error [ERROR 0x88982F72 :Failed to read from the stream]

Tags: windows, metadata

On adding details on a jpeg images like title,tags etc gives the following error(Windows 10 /64 bit)-

> ERROR 0x88982F72 :Failed to read from the stream

I have changed the security settings to "**FULL CONTROL**" for all groups and users but the error still persists.

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your copy of Windows is not activated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 (even the unactivated version ) by default does not let users (even with Full Control/admin ) to change the metadata of a file imported from another computer as a security measure.
But it does provide an option to override this measure (refer image) by unblocking it.
Once the "**Unblock option is checked**" and applied ,the metadata of the file can be changed.

[Unblock Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5zun.jpg)
[Changed Metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6XM8.jpg)